# Determine if each of the following graphs is connected and/or super-connected. Briefly justify your responses.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, random-graphs, directed-graphs, graph-connectivity

I am struggling to answer this question, and I was hoping for some assistance and/or help, it would be greatly appreciated.

This link is a screenshot of the question because it does include diagrams:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMVod.png

The question includes a definition that is used to answer the question; if anyone knows how to answer or go about this, you would be helping me out a lot.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Do you know what "connected" means in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G_1$ is connected since you can form a path between any two vertex. In other words, you can see that the graph is formed by "one piece" (it is just a line). In the case of superconnectivity, I don't know if you understand the concept, but for the first graph, what happens if you remove a point and all edges that incide? For example, if you remove $v_6$ and the edges that incide, the graph is "separated" into "two pieces", and therefore it isn't superconnected. It is the same in the remaining graphs. Remember that this property has to be satisfied **for all** vertex. I hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you so so much Daniel for explaining that and for your time! That all makes a lot of sense! When you mentioned removing v6, would that relate to part (b)?...Part B) Prove that every tree on at least three vertices is not super-connected

Comment: Exactly, since a tree has not any cycles, and therefore when you remove an edge, the tree is broken into "two pieces" since you have removed the only thing that connected those "pieces". In fact, if it weren't like that (if it were another path so that these "pieces" remain connected), a cycle could be formed, which is in contradiction with the fact that it is a tree.